# i have implemented Phonegap Sqlite Plugin-warnings

Tags: javascript, android, database, sqlite, cordova

i have tried implementing the plug-in for SQLite as mentioned in this blog [**here**](http://gauravstomar.blogspot.ca/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+GauravSTomarBootstrappingIntelligence+%28Gaurav+S+Tomar+:+Bootstrapping+Intelligence%29) .

my changes in the coding

```
 try 
        {
            File dbFile = getDatabasePath("abc.db");
            if(!dbFile.exists()){
                System.out.println("current db path:"+getDatabasePath("abc.db"));
                this.copy("abc.db",dbFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("db path:"+dbFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }
         } 
         catch (Exception e)
         {
         e.printStackTrace();
         }

    //And our copy function:


    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

  void copy(String file, String folder) throws IOException 
    {
     File CheckDirectory;
     CheckDirectory = new File(folder);


     String parentPath = CheckDirectory.getParent();

     File filedir = new File(parentPath);
     if (!filedir.exists()) {
         if (!filedir.mkdirs()) {
             return;
         }
     }

        InputStream in = this.getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(file);
        File newfile = new File(folder);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newfile);


        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len; while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) out.write(buf, 0, len);
        in.close(); out.close();
    }
```

i have just added the Sqlite (database) file alone in the **Assets folder**
and the  [**PhoneGap-SQLitePlugin-Android**](https://github.com/brodyspark/PhoneGap-SQLitePlugin-Android/blob/master/Android/src/com/phonegap/plugin/sqlitePlugin/SQLitePlugin.java) only these 2 java files.

**i get the warning as FILENOTFOUNDEXCEPTION, when i get the path it shows as**

```
04-17 19:06:46.370: I/System.out(8101): current db path:/data/data/com.a.b.c/databases/abc.db
```

**I am using cordova 2.5.0 and i changed the android from 4.1.2 to 2.2 and using the updated version of plugin updated 4 months ago..**

I don't know where i have gone wrong.

Comment: What does getDatabasePath() do?