# phonegap Sqlite plugin implementation-error and warning:no such table

Tags: javascript, android, database, sqlite, cordova

I implemented the Phonegap plugin as mentioned in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968009/i-have-implemented-phonegap-sqlite-plugin-warnings).

I am getting an error as there is no such table as given in query.whereas there is a table in that name.

**CODE**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf=8" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="SQLitePlugin.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() 
    {
        var db =  window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("abc.db", "1.0", "test", 20000);

        db.transaction(function(tx) 
        {
            tx.executeSql("SELECT column_name FROM table_name;", [], function(tx) 
            {
                console.log("column_name length: " + column_name.length);

          });
        }, 
        function(e) 
        {
        console.log("ERROR: " + e.message);
        });

      }

  </script>

**Error and Warnings**

    04-12 18:11:58.271: D/dalvikvm(400): VFY: dead code 0x0047-0067 in Lcom/phonegap/plugin/sqlitePlugin/SQLitePlugin;.results2string (Landroid/database/Cursor;)Ljava/lang/String;
    04-12 18:11:58.281: V/info(400): Open sqlite db: /data/data/com.a.android.b/databases/abc.db.db
    04-12 18:11:58.351: D/CordovaLog(400): SQLitePluginTransaction - this.trans_id:1365770518342000
    04-12 18:11:58.351: I/Web Console(400): SQLitePluginTransaction - this.trans_id:1365770518342000 at file:///android_asset/www/SQLitePlugin.js:83
    04-12 18:11:58.351: D/CordovaLog(400): SQLitePluginTransaction.prototype.executeSql
    04-12 18:11:58.362: I/Web Console(400): SQLitePluginTransaction.prototype.executeSql at file:///android_asset/www/SQLitePlugin.js:164
    04-12 18:11:58.362: D/CordovaLog(400): success not null:SELECT column_name FROM table_name;
    04-12 18:11:58.362: I/Web Console(400): success not null:SELECT type FROM tpl_category; at file:///android_asset/www/SQLitePlugin.js:171
    04-12 18:11:58.362: D/CordovaLog(400): executeSql - add_to_transactionSELECT column_name FROM table_name;
    04-12 18:11:58.362: I/Web Console(400): executeSql - add_to_transactionSELECT column_name FROM table_name; at file:///android_asset/www/SQLitePlugin.js:199
    04-12 18:11:58.383: D/CordovaLog(400): SQLitePluginTransaction.prototype.complete
    04-12 18:11:58.383: I/Web Console(400): SQLitePluginTransaction.prototype.complete at file:///android_asset/www/SQLitePlugin.js:204
    04-12 18:11:58.391: I/Database(400): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: tpl_category
    04-12 18:11:58.391: W/System.err(400): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: table_name: , while compiling: SELECT column_name FROM table_name;
    04-12 18:11:58.391: W/System.err(400):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
    04-12 18:11:58.391: W/System.err(400):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
    04-12 18:11:58.391: W/System.err(400):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
    04-12 18:11:58.391: W/System.err(400):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
    04-12 18:11:58.401: W/System.err(400):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:46)
    04-12 18:11:58.401: W/System.err(400):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
    04-12 18:11:58.401: W/System.err(400):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
    04-12 18:11:58.401: W/System.err(400):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1315)
    04-12 18:11:58.401: W/System.err(400):  at com.phonegap.plugin.sqlitePlugin.SQLitePlugin.executeSqlBatch(SQLitePlugin.java:263)
    04-12 18:11:58.401: W/System.err(400):  at com.phonegap.plugin.sqlitePlugin.SQLitePlugin.execute(SQLitePlugin.java:109)
    04-12 18:11:58.401: W/System.err(400):  at org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:61)
    04-12 18:11:58.401: W/System.err(400):  at org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:220)
    04-12 18:11:58.401: W/System.err(400):  at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:44)
    04-12 18:11:58.401: W/System.err(400):  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaChromeClient.onJsPrompt(CordovaChromeClient.java:221)
    04-12 18:11:58.401: W/System.err(400):  at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:566)
    04-12 18:11:58.401: W/System.err(400):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    04-12 18:11:58.401: W/System.err(400):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    04-12 18:11:58.412: W/System.err(400):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    04-12 18:11:58.412: W/System.err(400):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-12 18:11:58.412: W/System.err(400):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    04-12 18:11:58.412: W/System.err(400):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    04-12 18:11:58.412: W/System.err(400):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    04-12 18:11:58.412: W/System.err(400):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    04-12 18:11:58.412: V/executeSqlBatch(400): SQLitePlugin.executeSql(): Error=no such table: table_name: , while compiling: SELECT column_name FROM table_name;
    04-12 18:11:58.412: V/executeSqlBatch(400): 1365770518342000
    04-12 18:11:58.432: D/CordovaLog(400): SQLitePluginTransaction.txErrorCallback---transId:1365770518342000
    04-12 18:11:58.432: I/Web Console(400): SQLitePluginTransaction.txErrorCallback---transId:1365770518342000 at file:///android_asset/www/SQLitePlugin.js:132
    04-12 18:11:58.444: D/CordovaLog(400): ERROR: undefined
    04-12 18:11:58.444: I/Web Console(400): ERROR: undefined at file:///android_asset/www/view all.html:27
```

Have I missed any initialization or declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this and follow this [its working!](https://github.com/k4ml/halal-android)

Have phonegap OF **2.1.0 version**
android OF **2.2**
Jquery OF **1.8.2min**(if you use)i did not use Jquery.

I TRIED THE SAME WITH THE RECENT VERSION OF PHONEGAP **2.5.0**, ANDROID **4.1.2** & NEW SQLITE PLUGIN UPDATED 7 MONTHS AGO...IT DID NOT WORK....

**FINALLY AFTER ALMOST 4-5 DAYS I FOUND A SOLUTION!!**

YIPEE!!

Answer (score 1):

Well i found the answer to this post of mine. But this has put me into a new problem.

ASSUMPTIONS made by me...

I had put the .sqlite in the assets/www folder.so i assumed that the eclipse is opening  that particular sqlite folder.

**Code:**

```
var db =  window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("abc.db", "1.0", "test", 20000);
```

Database formed was abc.db.db.that was my another mistake.So,when i gave the command to access the tables through the command

```
tx.executeSql("SELECT column_name FROM table_name;", [], function(tx) 
    {
        console.log("column_name length: " + column_name.length);

  });
}, 
function(e) 
{
console.log("ERROR: " + e.message);
});
```

**it showed me an error as no such table_name.**

**IN FACT,IT CREATED A NEW .DB FILE(according to my code)WHICH DID NOT HAVE SUCH A TABLE INSIDE IT.**

it was fully my mistake.

but,this makes me think further how am i gonna make eclipse access my .sqlite file,to integrate it for my Phonegap application?

**ANY SUGGESTIONS AND SOLUTIONS PLEASE LET ME KNOW..**

Comment: This is correct behaviour. If you want to package a sql lite db with your app you need to copy it to the applications data directory.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a bug in Cordova 2.6, I just upgraded from 2.5 today and all my sqlite code seems to have broke though I did make some other changes. I keep getting the same error but am 90% sure its cordova related.

04-17 02:21:08.722: E/Web Console(1698): "no such table: api (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM api WHERE md5 = ? LIMIT 1" at file:///android_asset/www/js/app.js:9249

But I don't get any errors when I create the database and tables AND I can directly explore the database within eclipse using the file explorer and see that not only the database exists but the table is there as well.

Ill report any solution i find.

EDIT: I rolled back to cordova 2.5 and everything seems to be working for me now. That might work as a temporary fix until the issue is tracked down.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link, it's working for me.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

Comment: Rajapandiyan JJ,this is working but i have an SQLite database and i want to implement that and access the same.